# Custom configurations with XcodeGen

Tags: xcode, automation, xcodegen

I'm trying to automate the process of setting up a new app with [XcodeGen](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen). How can I achieve custom Project Configurations like in the screenshot with a YML file?

[image]

I expected to be able to do it like this, like the [docs](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/blob/master/Docs/ProjectSpec.md#configs) say:

```
name: Test1
settings:
  configs:
    Alpha: alpha-com.company.Test1
    Beta: beta-com.company.Test1
    Debug: debug-com.company.Test1
    Release: com.company.Test1
options:
  bundleIdPrefix: com.company
targets:
  Test1:
    type: application
    platform: iOS
    sources: Test1
  Test1Tests:
    type: bundle.unit-test
    platform: iOS
    schemetestTargets: Test1Tests
    sources: Test1Tests
```

But this doesn't work. I have tried several options, like removing the settings Level above it, placing it in the target setting with & without config level. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/issues/455) is what achieves the desired result:

```
configs:
  Alpha: release
  Beta: release
  Debug: debug
  Release: release
targets:
  Test1:
    settings:
      configs:
        Alpha:
          PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER: alpha-com.company.Test1
        Beta:
          PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER: beta-com.company.Test1
        ...
```